# Deleted question - bounty refund

Tags: support, bounty

I just found out that one of the questions I offered bounty for, turned out to be deleted. I am wondering whether it is viable/possible to refund bounty on such questions?

Here is a [**link**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18103/extraction-of-veins-from-sclera-image). The question turned out to be very low quality and a complete misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to see whether it's possible.  It looks like [questions with OPEN bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27103/131640) can have the bounties refunded, but I can't see that option on that question... which was closed in October 2014 (so it doesn't have an open bounty).

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172556/so-points-changed-50-for-no-reason) suggests that you should receive the bounty back automatically, though.

I can see the bounty refund on your profile, but it says the value was zero?

[image]

Comment: Thank you Peter. I can't find it in history of my points from that period. It should be 50. Unless it is a bug of some sort, I don't really care about those points.

Comment: You're welcome!  You will probably be able to have a poke around yourself in a day or two. You have my vote, at least. :-)

Comment: Thank you Peter, vice-versa! ;)